# VLOOKUP to find weeknumber

Tags: excel

I'm sure there is a more appropriate method for this, but I have layers of referencing so it has to be done this way. My spreadsheet is like an onion.

I need to be able to pull the week number based on a value defined in another sheet. So far the user enters the date when they start the sheet up. It is always the 1st of the month. This is then reference for a host of things elsewhere. This value is currently in `=Front!$C$3`. I have a visual calender set up as 53 rows, with 1 row per seven day period. I had written `=VLOOKUP(O25, $S$2:$Z$54, 1, FALSE )` which had worked on a two column table for another task with different referencing. Currently I get `#N/A` as the return.

[image]

I'm assuming there is a way to have the cell check the red area for a value matching 1/1/23 (formatted as a custom format to just show the day number) and return the value in column 1 (the week number)

In my case O25:O36 is just 1/1/23:1/12/23. N25:N36 is the same just referencing the adjacent cell for O.

If there is a more straight forward way of having a cell return the weeknumber for the first day of each month, so I can have a cell on `Front!` return the week number based on the value in `=Front!$C$3` that would be ideal also.

Comment: Did you check [WEEKNUM function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340)?

Comment: Are you waiting for me to post questions foxfire, damn! I will have a gander. Thanks

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Gonna need you on speed dial mate! WEEKNUM isn't the right function but it had ISOWEEKNUM as a suggested func and that is perfect! This isn't my job hence why I need to ask for help fairly often, just a secondary duty I have picked up some how...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the second time to @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns again, for pointing out a simple answer. ISOWEEKNUM with the dates of the first of the month has resolved.

```
=ISOWEEKNUM("1/1/23")
```